# What information is contained in the AWS EC2 Key pair?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS does not ask any information other than key name while generating the key pair. My old keys are leaked and I want to know if it can be potentially harmful. They cannot be used for login as I changed the instance. But if decrypted, what information will be revealed?

(I checked the forum but could not find a clear answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. Your key pair is the encryption key used for SSH traffic. But the key itself is generated from random data.

Comment: Ok... but I read here (in 7th line) - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html that "Anyone who possesses your private key can decrypt your login information, so it's important that you store your private keys in a secure place." What do they mean by login information?

Comment: It means if *you* are still using the compromised key to connect to the instance, then the content of your ssh connections is not secure, because the possessor has what they need in order to decrypt them.